# Test functions with Jest and Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

How can I test this function with Jest and Enzyme?

```
addProducts = id => {
    toast.success("Product added", {
        position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT
    });
    history.push(`/product/${id}`);
};
```

I was using this snippet of code but it was not enough...

```
it("Must return added addProduct with success message", () => {
    const componente = shallow(<AddProduct />);

    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "addProducts");

    expect(spy).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are carring our unit testing, you can test for 2 things over here:

1) `toast.success()` is called with the right parameters, which is `'Product added'` and the object `{ position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT }`

2) `history.push()` is being called, and that history.push is being called correctly.

For both of the above, you will have to call `jest.spyOn()` on both of them, and then check that they are being called once.

```
expect(toastSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
expect(historyPushSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
```

In addition, you will need to assert that the above mocks are being called correctly.

```
const toastSpyCall = toastSpy.mock.calls[0][0];

// expect(...).toBe(....)
```